# column object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyspark, databricks

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(df['age'],df['concrete_strength'])
plt.title('Scatter Plot of Age vs. Concrete Compressive Strength')
plt.xlabel('Age(days)')
plt.ylabel('Concrete Compressive Strength (MPa)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I got error that column object is not callable in databrics.
I tried indexing and same thing is coming

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use Python function on a spark Column objects directly, unless it is intended to operate on Column objects / expressions. One solution is to udf (used defined function) for that:

```
@udf
def plot(df):
  plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
  plt.scatter(df['age'],df['concrete_strength'])
  plt.title('Scatter Plot of Age vs. Concrete Compressive Strength')
  plt.xlabel('Age(days)')
  plt.ylabel('Concrete Compressive Strength (MPa)')
  plt.grid(True)
  plt.show()
```